# unable to start ONOS SDN controller from root user

Tags: python, bash, sdn, onos

I'm doing a POC on SDN using miniedit (UI of mininet) and ONOS as a SDN controller, I want to invoke ONOS from miniedit when we run the topology so used the following line of code in python

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"/home/paxterra/onos/tools/dev/bin/onos-karaf; exec bash\"' &")
```

this invokes ONOS if i execute it as a normal user, but throws error since this code present in miniedit.py and I'm running miniedit.py as super user.

```
Error : /home/paxterra/onos/tools/dev/bin/onos-karaf: line 7: onos-setup-karaf: command not found
```

I tried to set environment variable `PATH="/home/paxterra/onos/tools/dev/bin/"` and then tried the command again, it gives the same error.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. ?

Comment: Have you tried executing the command with the subprocess module yet? (subprocess.call ) ?

Comment: Yes i tried with subprocess.call() and subprocess.Popen() as well, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When using `sudo`, the path variable is not preserved by default. `Sudo` has its own path variable. This is a security design.

since `onos-setup-karaf` is not in the path (ie you use full path for onos-karaf but onos-setup-karaf is probably not in your working dir) you should try to execute `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" miniedit` or however you start that program but you need to preserve the path variable.